# kill running process in test golang

Tags: http, testing, go, server

Writing a program based on `http.ListenAndServe` and writing the tests i've hit a stump. my test looks like this

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "../"
)

func TestServer(t *testing.T) {
    Server.Server()
}
```

and the tested function

```
package Server

import (
    "net/http"
)

var (
    DefaultPort = "8080"
    DefaultDir = "."
)

func Server() {
    port := DefaultPort
    directory := DefaultPort

    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, http.FileServer(http.Dir(directory)))
}
```

my goal is to be able to run test and after the server listener is launched kill it and return a success message

Comment: Try changing the test package to `package Server` and removing the import statements. Then do `go run -test`. It's simplest if the file containing the test functions (which should be named something like `server_test.go`) has the same package declaration as the package being tested. Have a look at http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Testing .

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To be able to stop, you need to create Listener by hand

```
listener, err := net.Listen("http", ":"+port)
err=http.Serve(listener, http.FileServer(http.Dir(directory)))
```

then you can

```
err=listener.Close()
```